# Make this table column width fit just nice. Not too wide, not too narrow

Tags: css, angularjs, html, ngtable

I am using angularjs ngtable module to create this table.

Here is the relevant html code;

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl" class="container">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>remarks</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="test in $data">
            <td data-title="'name'" >
                {{test.name}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'remarks'">
                {{test.remarks}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The `name` string happens to be very short. Sometimes, it is at most 5 characters. Sometimes, at most 3 characters. The column width for `name` is usually wider than necessary. How to make this column fit just nice?

Comment: Are you using any front-end framework?

Comment: yes, I'm using angularjs

Comment: what is the CSS for `.table` and `.table-bordered`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it with css. Add an extra class to your table e.g. `table-expand`

so your table will be

```
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-expand">
```

and the css for this class

```
.table-expand tbody tr td:nth-child(1n) {
    white-space:nowrap;
}

.table-expand tbody tr td:nth-child(2n) {
    width:100%
}
```

see this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7woanugh/1/)

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. It works. But I have problems understanding the code. How do you choose the `nth-child(1n)` stuff? How would I know whether to use `1n` or `2n` or `3n`? Any documentation that you can point me to? why is 2nd column `width:100%`?

Comment: You gave a table with two columns, and you want the first to fit its contents. So you have to make the second column to expand so `width:100%`. But you don't want the contents of the first column to wrap so `white-space:nowrap`.  If you had an other table with more columns, then the css would change, depends on what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know with ng-table, but I do about the same thing, like this

```
<table>
    <colgroup>
        <col span="1" style="width: 10%;">
        <col span="1" style="width: 90%;">
    </colgroup>
```

This would cause `name` to only have 10% of the width

Another solution would be the set the `table` to `fixed` using css, then set the set the `width` on each `th` and `td`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the width of the column dependent on the content of `test.name`, determine the number of characters in the longest name and set the width of the column based on character count.

**JS**

```
$scope.data = [
    {name: 'a', remarks: 'remark a'},
    {name: 'b', remarks: 'remark b'},
    {name: 'c', remarks: 'remark c'},
    {name: 'defghijk', remarks: 'remark c'}
  ];

  var maxLength = $scope.data.sort(function (a, b) { 
    return (b.name.length - a.name.length); 
  })[0];

  $scope.width = maxLength.name.length * 10 + 'px'
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app class="container">
    <table ng-controller="TestCtrl" class="table table-bordered" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width={{width}}>name</th>
                <th>remarks</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="test in data">
                <td data-title="'name'" >
                    {{test.name}}
                </td>
                <td data-title="'remarks'">
                    {{test.remarks}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/8s2720zh/).